# SQL needed to get most popular product based also off a quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to get the most popular productID from my MSSQL Database. This is what the table looks like (With a bit of dummy data):

OrderItems:

```
+--+-------+--------+---------+
|ID|OrderID|Quantity|ProductID|
+--+-------+--------+---------+
| 1|      1|       1|        1|
| 2|      1|       1|        2|
| 3|      2|       1|        1|
| 4|      2|      50|        2|
```

The OrderID field can be ignored, but I need to find the most popular ProductID's from this table, ordering them by how often they occur. The results set should look something like this:

```
+--------+
|PoductID|
+--------+
|       2|
|       1|
```

As ProductID 2 has a total quantity of 51, it needs to come out first, followed by ProductID 1 which only has a total quantity of 2.

(Note: Query needs to be compatible back to MSSQL-2008)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT
  productID
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  productID
ORDER BY
  SUM(Quantity) DESC
```

`GROUP BY` allows `SUM()`, but you don't have to use it in the `SELECT` to be allowed to use it in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. We had it working with quantity, however we were using ORDER BY Count(*) instead of SUM(Quantity). Didn't expect SUM to act in that way.. Will accept the answer when it lets me

Comment: The aggregate functions are applied to each group defined by the group by clause :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select ProductID
from OrderItems
group by ProductId
order by sum(Quantity) desc;
```